# Why does JBoss web app work fine without web.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jboss

I'm developing my first web application with JBoss with Eclipse Luna and Windfly as server. Looking in the WEB-INF i cannot find the web.xml file. It is all ok, the application works, but where are the web.xml settings located? How can i change, for example, the class-URL associations?
Please note that i can't see any annotation inside the classes i've coded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from java ee 6, web.xml is no longer required for a web app to deploy. Instead of using xml, you can use annotations to replace the xml file.

Here you can find the correspondence between annotations and old web.xml elements

https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations

For example, class and url assocations are resolved using @WebServlet

```
@WebServlet(name="testServlet", urlPatterns={"/hello"})
```

Comment: I have created the web.xml file, but it seems that any change doesn't affect the web app in any way. Is it normal?

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.coderanch.com/t/569970/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/web-xml-annotations

Answer (score 1):

When you create Dynamic Web Project with Eclipse you can choose Dynamic Web Project module. To create project with deployment descriptor web.xml you must choose 2.5 version. Because 3.0 version uses annotations not xml configuration.
To generate web.xml

> right click on your project -> Java EE Tools -> Generate deployment
>   descriptor.

To use only web.xml you must change version of your Dynamic Web Project module to 2.5 go to .settings directory in your project folder and change jstl.web param to 2.5 in file org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

To check the changes was made go to

> Project Properties-> Project Facets
>   and  find Dynamic Web Module line.

Comment: That's fine, but i actually can't find any annotation inside my Servlets classes; i'm just learning and it's better for me to follow tutorials (all tells about the web.xml file...), so is there a way to 'force' the current Dynamic web project to use the web.xml file?

Comment: Does it "force" the web app to apply the web.xml settings only? Do you know where are current settings actually placed?